# Can't connect cable modem/router to load balancing router

Tags: networking, router, cable-modem

I just had my cable modem replaced by the ISP because it was an older model that stopped working because of a change in technology.

This new device is a Humax HGB10R-02. It's both a cable modem and an Ethernet/WiFi router.

When the ISP technician installed it I tested it connected directly to one computer via Ethernet and it worked. I also asked for the technician to disable WiFi because I have mesh WiFi routers.

Then I tested with this new device connected to a TP-Link TL-ER605, which is my load balancing router, but that didn't work. I said I would take a look into this later and dismissed the technician.

Now I first tested the new device connected via Ethernet to another computer and it didn't work. It didn't even manage to open a connection. I connected it back to the first computed that I had tested before and it worked.

I did some more tests and I managed to make the second computer work when I connected it to the new device's second Ethernet port. I did some more tests and then the second computer started working connected to the first Ethernet port.

Then I tested the load balancing router again. However, I could not make it connect on either of the 4 Ethernet ports.

I tried to access the new device's interface but I got a 404 error when I tried to access `192.168.0.1`. I'm not sure this is the right address but I think it is because the 404 error looked customized, making me believe that it connected but it's configured to not allow me to access it.

What can I do to make the load balancing router connect to this new device?

Comment: I just went through this with my own ISP.   Can you connect a computer directly to the new Modem and see what main internal IP address it gives you.   We would need that information.

Comment: @John Is this enough? https://pastebin.com/6gHN65Bz The Windows output has been translated from Portuguese.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Tried that but no change. Tried to the same to the load balancer but no change either.